# LoadLibrary : crash in release mode

Tags: c++, winapi, release

I use the function `LoadLibrary` from the Windows API to load dynamically a DLL (compiled in release mode). Then I call an imported function `my_function`

When my exe is compiled in:

- **DEBUG mode**: no issue
- **RELEASE mode w/ debug info**: no issue
- **RELEASE mode w/out debug info**: it crashes after `LoadLibrary` call, when I call the imported function `my_function`

Here's a code sample:

**MyClass.cpp:**

```
#include "myclass.h" 

typedef int (__stdcall *f_my_function)(char*, int*); 

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    mDllHandler = NULL;
}

bool MyClass::loadLibrary()
{

    qCritical() << "Loading library";
    mDllHandler = LoadLibrary(L"my.dll");
    qCritical() << "Library loaded";

    if (!mDllHandler) {
        qCritical() << "Error : could not load my.dll";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool MyClass::freeLibrary()
{
    if(!mDllHandler) {
        qCritical() << "Error : DLL handler is null";
        return false;
    }
    if(!FreeLibrary(mDllHandler)) {
        qCritical() << "Error : could not unload my.dll";
        return false;
    }
    mDllHandler = NULL;

    return true;
}

bool MyClass::myFunction(const& QString str)
{
    if(!mDllHandler) {
        qCritical() << "Error : DLL handler is null";
        return false;
    }
    f_my_function my_function = (f_my_function)GetProcAddress(mDllHandler, "my_function");
    if (!my_function) {
        qCritical() << "Error : Could not resolve the function my_function";
        return false;
    }

    int size = str.size();
    char* string = str.toLatin1().data();

    int error = my_function(string, &size);

    qDebug() << "my_function : Error code is " << error;

    return !error;
}
```

**MyClass.h:**

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <QString>

class MyClass
{

public:
    MyClass();
    bool loadLibrary();
    bool freeLibrary();
    bool myFunction(const QString& str = "");


private:
    HINSTANCE mDllHandler;


};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyClass myClass;

    myClass.loadLibrary();
    myClass.myFunction();
    myClass.freeLibrary();

    return a.exec();

}
```

I really have no idea why it crashes here.

EDIT : Here I don't have access to the source code of my.dll.

Comment: Perchance, what horrors are living in your `DllMain` of `my.dll`?

Comment: What does *"it crashes"* mean? Where does it *"crash"*? What's the callstack at the point of failure?

Comment: This question sadly misses out the pertinent detail. The code presented is fine, so long as the library being loaded is coded correctly. The problem lies in that library, but we know nothing of it.

Comment: I have updated my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well the crash (which eventually did not occur always at LoadLibrary call, but sometimes later in the code) was due to a wrong declaration of the imported functions.

In MyClass.cpp :

**Wrong declaration:**

```
typedef int (__stdcall *f_my_function)(char*, int*);
```

**Correct declaration:**

```
typedef int (*f_my_function)(char*, int*);
```

Indeed I wrongly declared `f_my_function` with `__stdcall`

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. The code in the question doesn't import any functions. It just calls `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: Would be so much better if you add the parameter names to the type definitions for readability. Can't bear type definitions without the parameter names.